# Loading external page/link from Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to load some external files and/or links in the bootstrap tabs but unsuccessful. I noticed there are also a number of other posts with similar questions but their solutions doesn't seem to work...

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4V2Ly/) but I am not sure why it doesn't work...

fiddle js

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url, function (result) {
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});

// load first tab content
$('#home').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"), function (result) {
    $('.active a').tab('show');
});
```

I have also upload it to [c9 workspace](https://c9.io/jch02140/test/workspace/index.html) and it partially works there (except tabs with external links and files)

Answer (score 0):

**Tab C** works, but its contents are hidden:

[image]

.. Try removing the fade class:

```
$('#home').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"), function(result) {
  $('.active a').tab('show');

  // NEW CODE
  $(href).find('.fade').removeClass('.fade');
  // END NEW CODE
});
```

---

**Tab D** does not work because the URL requested probably doesn't exist:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi simonwjackson. 

Thanks for your reply. I tried adding your code into  the javascript but it doesn't seem to fix the problem... Also, I noticed external pages work if they are in another folder. I have updated the [c9 workspace](https://c9.io/jch02140/test/workspace/index.html).

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the problem.. Turns out I added some extra div class on the external page...